# getDrawingCache() always returning null

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to capture The content of ImageView by using DrawingCache. I written the below code.

```
iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
iv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);            
iv1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap myScreenshot = iv1.getDrawingCache();
iv2.setImageBitmap(myScreenshot);
```

But I am getting only one image on screen. Later I came to know **myScreenshot** is null

I saw many posts regarding same problem, but no proper solution.

I thought any permissions we have to add in manifest ? or root permission required to achieve this ? Please help me regarding this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try calling `buildDrawingCache()` before `getDrawingCache()`

**EDIT:**
Call `getDrawingCache()`, after the page have loaded, instead of `onCreate`

Comment: I added iv1.buildDrawingCache(); before getDrawingCache(). no use

Comment: did you check that iv1 has an image when the application runs. Also specify where exactly you are calling your code. You might be calling it before the views are initialized

Comment: in xml file only i am giving android:src for iv1. The code i posted here is after setContentView(R.layout.main); in onCreate() Is it correct ?

Comment: for the sake of debugging add a temporary button , and try executing the code on the button click, so that we can ensure that everything is loaded properly. Another question which comes to my mind is if iv1 is set in the xml, then in the onCreate method, it would probably have nothing other than what you have specified in the xml. So setting iv2 from iv1, in the onCreate doesn't make much sense. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me. My code is working, only problem is putting my code in onCreate() method. I tested it with a button. No need of buildDrawingCache() method.

Answer (score 2):

call getDrawingCache() in onWindowFocusChanged() and not in onCreate(), then you will not get null.

Answer (score 1):

You din't do 
`iv1.buildDrawingCache(true)`; add line before
`Bitmap myScreenshot = iv1.getDrawingCache();`

Comment: Your answer is the exact same answer as the accepted one written by @aqs

Answer (score 0):

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview);                 

imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview1);
```

use this two images is screan

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"               
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="486dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/iv1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_launcer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/iv2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```